# how do I join two meshes without leaving a gap?

Tags: mesh

i'm fairly new to the blender. I have these two meshes, the ragged one i need for the ground surface where the grass will be, the straight one i need for a road, how do i join them together without leaving a gap? Or is there a better way to make it out of a single mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you can use Ctrl-R to cut loops in the plane on the right to match the number you have on the left.(I subdivided mine because I was dealing with a full plane that was square, yours is probably not needing that)
[image]
Then you can use Looptools add-on to Bridge the edge loops once you select them both at the gap between the two parts.
[image]